# UserType in OSGi

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi

I have a very simple use case that does not work, and I think it might be the OSGi context I'm running Hibernate in, but I'm not sure:

```
@Entity(name = "Profile")
@Table(name = "profile")
@TypeDefs({ @TypeDef(name = "RawDataUserType", typeClass = RawDataUserType.class) })
public class ProfileEntity {

    @Column(name = "raw_data")
    @Type(type = "RawDataUserType")
    private RawData rawData;
}

public class RawDataUserType implements UserType {

    public RawDataUserType() {
        System.out.println("RawDataUserType.RawDataUserType()");
    }
    // actual implementation
 }
```

I can see that the constructor of the `RawDataUserType` is not called when the exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.acme.module.RawDataUserType, at table: profile, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(raw_data)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:411)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:384)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:529)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:464)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
```

OSGi classloaders often have problems finding classes, and at least [this person](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043330&view=next) seems to have the same problem (but no solution). However, `org.hibernate.osgi` should replace the classloader with something that works in OSGi.

To fix it I tried to add the following lines to the *Manifest.MF* (and no, it's not OSGi standard, but I would not care if it worked):

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: org.hibernate.core
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: global
```

Is it possible to use `UserType`s in OSGi? How?

Comment: This might be an issue in hibernate. I propose to open a jira issue there. Btw. Did you try this outside OSGi?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider There is no easy way to go from OSGi to not-OSGi. I've been trying for a while now, but I'd have to delete so much configuration and environment that it's basically a completely new use-case.

Comment: Are you using a JPA container, such as Apache Aries JPA, or using Hibernate's built in support?

Comment: @TimWard Hibernate's built in support.

Comment: You may wish to try Apache Aries JPA then. It does a lot of work to sort out classloading properly when using Hibernate in an OSGi environment.

Comment: @TimWard No, I don't wish to try Apache Aries. It was evaluated by some of our guys and it did not work with Hibernate for them.

Comment: @SteffiS. Apache Aries does do a fair amount of testing with Hibernate, so I'm surprised to hear that, but ok.

Comment: @TimWard I keep hearing that rumor, but it's just not true. Else the Hibernate JARs would have to be valid OSGi bundles, and [they're not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940914/how-to-use-hibernate-from-maven-central).

Comment: Aries JPA has the following test: https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa/blob/master/itests/jpa-container-itest/src/test/java/org/apache/aries/jpa/container/itest/JPAContainerHibernateTest.java, Aries Tx Control also has tests for a few versions of Hibernate: https://github.com/apache/aries/tree/trunk/tx-control/tx-control-providers/jpa/tx-control-jpa-itests/src/test/java/org/apache/aries/tx/control/itests